# how can i delete completely Spanner Instance?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

I can not create spanner instance by using nodejs client library.

> { Error: Creating an instance that is in the process of getting
>   deleted.
>       at /Users/Chipintoza/GSS Projects/accounts.gss.ge/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:442:17
>   code: 9,   metadata: Metadata { _internal_repr: {
>   'google.rpc.resourceinfo-bin': [Object] } },   note: 'Exception
>   occurred in retry method that was not classified as transient' }

I looked at Activity and yesterday when i deleted instance it turned out that the error occurred:

> Resource name  projects/spanner-gss-ge/instances/business-data Error
>   message    Deadline exceeded (HTTP 504): Deadline expired before
>   operation could complete.

On Console the Instance with this name is not listed.
How can i resolve this issue?

**As it is not deleted am i charged on daily basis?**

I have no problem with creating instance by the other name.

Comment: Hello. I'm on the Cloud Spanner engineering team. We're looking into this and we'll get you an answer soon.

Comment: Mike Thank you, I hope you and spanner teams will soon resolve this . 
There are many significant problems in NodeJS client library.
2017-04-02 i open issue.
[link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-node/issues/2176)
it is closed but it still **(3 month passed)** not resolved. (look at related)
Spinner does not have a free quota. and it's price is not small :(.
**If you can help them solve these problems soon, i will be very grateful.**
I will be assisting you and spanner teams as i can.

Comment: It turns out to be an issue on our side, in a rare case it takes a long time to clean up the metadata and that prevents you from creating the instance with the same name as previously deleted one. This should have no impact on the billing.

We are looking at the node js library issues.